# Create an outlet collection in Xcode 8

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode8, iboutletcollection

I'm building a macOS app using Xcode 8.3 and Swift. I have a simple view controller that contains a bunch of buttons that I'd like to put into an Outlet Collection but when I control-drag from a button to my Swift file, Outlet Collection is not presented as an option (my only options are Outlet and Action for the Connection type). Am I missing something? TIA

[image: try to create an outlet collection]

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that IB Outlet Collections have never been supported for macOS projects. :-(

Comment: This is correct. Outlet collections are feature of iOS, watchOS, and tvOS, but not macOS.

Comment: Thanks, I created an enhancement request.

Comment: @RobertJoseph - Did you find a workaround? Thank you.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte I just checked the bug report and Apple has still not responded. Sorry.